# How can I activate ssh-agent confirmation in MacOSX Leopard?

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, forwarding, agent

I have a MacBook with MacOSX Leopard (10.6.2) and I use it to connect to some servers (their O.S. is Debian Lenny) using SSH.  I use RSA keys to login to server **A**, and from there I "bounce" to other servers **B**, **C** and **D**.  I have activated agent forwarding in my laptop's `.ssh/config` for server **A** in order to be able to connect to **A** and then "bounce" from **A** to **B**, **C** or **D** without having to type my password every time. It works fine.

But I read that agent forwarding has one security flaw: if a hacker gets `root` access on server **A**, he will be able to hijack the agent forwarding mechanism and connect to servers **B**, **C** and **D** without any password.

Apparently, one solution is to use `ssh-add`'s `-c` option: it is supposed to ask me for confirmation every time server **A** wants to use my RSA key.  But for some reason, it fails:

```
miniquark@mylaptop:~$ ssh-add -c
Enter passphrase for /Users/miniquark/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /Users/miniquark/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/miniquark/.ssh/id_rsa)
The user has to confirm each use of the key
miniquark@mylaptop:~$ ssh serverA
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
miniquark@serverA's password:
```

Normally, I don't need to launch `ssh-add` manually, since MacOSX does it for me automatically when I launch an ssh connection that requires an RSA key.  So perhaps the solution would be to configure MacOSX to launch `ssh-add` with the `-c` option.  Unfortunately, I just cannot find that option.

If you have any other idea that would protect me from agent forwarding hijacking, I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just open a session to each target machine? That way you can have each connection in its own Terminal tab and avoid the security issue altogether.

Comment: I understand your point, but the problem is that I need to run some commands on server A which connect to servers B, C and D (backups, log comparisons...).  Also, servers B, C and D are not on the Internet: I have to go through server A to reach them (for security reasons).

Comment: If machine A is rooted, I wouldn't say the 'visitor' abusing your ssh-agent is the biggest problem. (Also, s/highjack/hijack/g)

Comment: Yes, if A is rooted, things are pretty bad.  Perhaps you're right, and it's a bit overkill to try and configure agent forwarding confirmation on my MacBook.  But if it's as simple as adding a line or two in some hidden configuration file, it probably won't hurt.  I was just hoping someone knew how to make it work on MacOSX (knowing that it works fine in Debian Lenny).  Anyway, thanks for the insight, and for the spelling hint.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The agent tries to run a helper program to prompt. On OS X this is not in place by default, so you'll need to provide one (at /usr/libexec/ssh-askpass). I'm currently using one similar to this:

```
#! /bin/sh  

#  
# An SSH_ASKPASS command for MacOS X  
#  
# Based on script by Joseph Mocker, Sun Microsystems


TITLE=${MACOS_ASKPASS_TITLE:-"SSH Agent"}  

DIALOG="display dialog \"$@\" buttons {\"Deny\", \"Allow\"} default button 2"
DIALOG="$DIALOG with title \"$TITLE\" with icon caution"  

result=`osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e "$DIALOG" -e 'end tell'`  

if [ "$result" = "button returned:Allow" ]; then
    exit 0 
else  
    exit 1  
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this page http://jcs.org/notaweblog/2011/04/19/making_openssh_on_mac_os_x_more_secure/ for Joshua Stein's solution